# Order by clause not working inside CASE,WHEN statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I was trying out many answers but below query says an "`error in the query`".
but still could not figure it out. please help to sort this **ORDER BY** issue

```
select m.feed_id,e.event_code,m.meeting_name,e.timestamp_updated,e.event_time,m.country_code,m.category
from event e, meeting m 
WHERE m.id = e.meeting_id
AND m.date = '2015-07-29'
AND m.feed_id IN (1,2)
AND m.status ='A'  
AND e.off_time IS NOT NULL
AND e.settle_status = 'R'  
AND e.settle_status != 'V'  
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN  m.country_code = 'AU' THEN  e.timestamp_updated               
 CASE WHEN  m.country_code <> 'AU' THEN  e.event_code  
END DESC
```

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN  m.country_code = 'AU' THEN e.timestamp_updated WHEN  m.country_code <> 'AU' THEN  e.event_code END DESC  `. Remove the second  `case`

Comment: @Ullas, Thanks. Its working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second `case` from the query.

**Query**

```
select m.feed_id,e.event_code,m.meeting_name,e.timestamp_updated,
e.event_time,m.country_code,m.category
from event e, meeting m 
WHERE m.id = e.meeting_id
AND m.date = '2015-07-29'
AND m.feed_id IN (1,2)
AND m.status ='A'  
AND e.off_time IS NOT NULL
AND e.settle_status = 'R'  
AND e.settle_status != 'V'  
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN  m.country_code = 'AU' THEN  e.timestamp_updated               
WHEN  m.country_code <> 'AU' THEN  e.event_code  
END DESC;
```

OR

```
select m.feed_id,e.event_code,m.meeting_name,e.timestamp_updated,
e.event_time,m.country_code,m.category
from event e, meeting m 
WHERE m.id = e.meeting_id
AND m.date = '2015-07-29'
AND m.feed_id IN (1,2)
AND m.status ='A'  
AND e.off_time IS NOT NULL
AND e.settle_status = 'R'  
AND e.settle_status != 'V'  
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN  m.country_code = 'AU' THEN  e.timestamp_updated               
ELSE e.event_code  
END DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) . I mean maybe you have to use " [] "for other cases?

Comment: Hi Qsprec, it is not needed !